# What about authentication on AngularJS apps?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, zend-framework, authentication

I'm opening this question because I need some opinions about AngularJS and user authentication...

So, actually I'm using angular on the client side and Zend on the server side. The server side authentication process is working well..

However, on the client side (I already have some code written) I would like to know what you do you think that are the best practices to do it? I mean some code examples (if it is possible)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You should checkout the [angular-app](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app) sample app. It has a good [security](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app/tree/master/client/src/common/security) model.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using some parts of that code. What do you think about this: on each route change I'm checking for the current user, however should I at this point make a request to the server to see if the session still alive or just check on the object from the client side?

Comment: I would check the `userObj` is not null, in order to confirm that the user is logged in. However, you should setup an interceptor on the $http service to watch for a 401 status code (meaning the user has been logged out). At this point you should load the login page and set the `userObj = null`. (p.s. when you're happy with the answer - please mark it as correct).

Comment: Okay. When you refer 401 status code are you referring to the http authentication, or are you telling to simply return the 401 status code ?

Comment: Your server should return a 401 HTTP status code whenever you make a request and the user is not authenticated. When you go to a new route, you will be likely requesting data from the server (to populate the page). If the user has since logged out, the server will return 401, and your app can show the login screen.

Comment: If your app takes advantage of extensive caching (and is not making requests to the server very often). You could add a timeout every 15 minutes, to ping the server to check if the user is still logged in.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! What can I do for password security/encryption?